# How to write isolated function instead of lambda for .filter method

Tags: slick

I want to write the content of `TableQuery[T].filter` method as an isolated function (e.g. `.filter(fun)`) instead form like `.filter(_.id === 3)`. However when `fun` is a generic function `fun[T]`, some implicit (conversion?) function is missed and won't pass the compiling.

For example

```
val s = Some("123")
TableQuery[ Table_Users ].filter(x =>
(if (s.isEmpty) x.device_id.isEmpty else x.device_id === s.get).asInstanceOf[Column[Boolean]])
```

The code above works, however I want to extract lambda `x => (if ...)` out to be a function, because it is a little bit long.

Then I have `compareNull` function

```
def compareNull[T]( field: Column[Option[T]], value : Option[T]) 
   = (if (value.isEmpty) field.isEmpty else field.get === (value.get)).asInstanceOf[Column[Boolean]]
```

The code won't compile unless replacing `T` with another type like `String`.
I got error `value === is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[T]`.

I guess some implicit functions are missed here. `===` has an implicit parameter with type `OptionMapper2`. However I don't know how to fill the "hole".

The table is very simple:

```
class Table_Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[ Users ]{
   def device_id = column[Option[String]]("user_devicde_id",O.Nullable)
   def * = (device_id ) <> ( Users.tupled, Users.unapply)
}
```

Comment: Is adding a second argument list (implicit tt: TypedType[T]) sufficient? You probably need to import scala.slick.ast.TypedType

Comment: thanks again @cvogt. Unfortunately I got the same error `value === is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[T]`.

Comment: Try BaseTypedType instead. You can see the corresponding Slick code here https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/66a9b4100c458272727643f81e886f6546c41706/src/main/scala/scala/slick/lifted/ExtensionMethods.scala#L225

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: @cvogt, Hi I just tried it. It works!!!! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a second argument list `(implicit tt: BaseTypedType[T])`